# Indent code when using lambda expressions in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, lambda

By default, intellisense in visual studio reorganize and indent your code when you
create a lamba sub() in vb.net. Something like the code example below (example 1).

I always try to organice it but I am very used to c# and I do not feel that it is
readable, so I try to decorate it with some line jumps as you can see in Example 2.

What do you think is the best method to display code in vb.net when you declare
lamba expressions?.

Examples are welcome.

**Please, do not edit the post to INDENT Example1. It is written that way on purpose.
It is default intellisense indent.**

**Example 1:**

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(Sub(x)

                                                      Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
                                                      For i As Integer = 0 To 10
                                                          Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                                                          Console.WriteLine("From Queued Item")
                                                      Next

                                                      Parallel.Invoke(New Action(Sub()
                                                                                     Console.WriteLine("From Action1")
                                                                                 End Sub),
                                                                                            New Action(Sub()
                                                                                                           Console.WriteLine("From Action2")
                                                                                                       End Sub),
                                                                                             New Action(Sub()
                                                                                                            Console.WriteLine("From Action3")
                                                                                                        End Sub))
                                                  End Sub))
```

**Example 2:**

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( _
        New WaitCallback( _
            Sub(x)

                Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
                For i As Integer = 0 To 10
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                    Console.WriteLine("From Queued Item")
                Next

                Parallel.Invoke( _
                    New Action(Sub()
                                   Console.WriteLine("From Action1")
                               End Sub),
                   New Action(Sub()
                                  Console.WriteLine("From Action2")
                              End Sub),
                  New Action(Sub()
                                 Console.WriteLine("From Action3")
                             End Sub))
            End Sub))
```

Comment: To my way of thinking anything that keeps more of the code on the visible area is more readable.

Comment: There is "pretty listing" option you can uncheck in tools-options-text editor-basic-vb specific. But then nothing gets formatted. At his point, you can write your own add-on to format the code the way you want